# JMeter and random variable along with if controller

Tags: jmeter

i want to control my sampler execution by using a random variable . I have a sequence of hits login,welcome,Bla,log out . i want the log out to be performed for 6/10 requests and let others do not login(so to speak 6 requests will perform the whole sequence including log out, 4 of them will perform will not perform log out ).How to achieve the same in JMETER

I have added a random variable rand and set it between 1-10 at the beginning of the thread group .Then just above Logout sampler i placed an IF controller were i check ${rand}>4 . How ever i always get all sequence executed . Please suggest what am i doing wrong

Comment: correction:let other request sets do not perform log out

Comment: make sure rand is an int and not a string, can you should how you randomized ? you can use Random Variable

Answer (score 1):

This was accomplished by creating a combination of config element- random variable  and an IF controller

1) a random variable was created with Minim and maxim value to meet above condition
2) and IF controller was able to check  ${myrand}>4;

This had derived the desired result - thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a little bit weird, my expectation is that the problem is in the following areas:

1. Your IF Controller condition is wrong (check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries)
2. Your random variable setting is wrong, i.e. it has the same value for all virtual users (threads) so they will either be executed all or none

So I would recommend using [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) or [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) in order to set up this 60/40 distribution.

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Random Variable in Jmeter is saved in long format be default so

${rand} > 4 won't work. You need to change

Condition to ${rand} > 4.0

or change Random Variable Output format to 00 (2 digits)

see [Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Variable)